# Times New Roman font for custom class

Tags: fonts, margins

I am new to using LaTeX in general, and I am using a custom documentclass (`.cls` file seems to be generated from a `.dtx` file) to prepare a work report. I am struggling to change the
font to *Times New Roman* for the entire report; I used the following command as suggested in
the answers to similar questions posted here, but the resulting PDF document somehow got
`NimbusRomNo9L-Regu`:

```
\documentclass[ece]{uw-wkrpt}

%WORKAROUND to change the report body font size to 11pt
\let\savednewcommand\newcommand
\let\newcommand\renewcommand
\makeatletter
\input{size11.clo}
\makeatother
\let\newcommand\savednewcommand

%Times new Roman
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

I also need to modify the margin of `lettersize` paper. Your help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I tried using `geometry` package for changing margins, but it did not change the margin of the output. I noticed some codes in the `.dtx` file that seems to set
all margins to be `1.5in`; I need this to be changed so that left margin is set at `1.5in` while others are set at `1.0in`:

```
% The left and right margins will be set to 1.5 inches wide; the top
% and bottom margins will be set to 1.0 inches wide.  This is required
% by Section 9.8.5 of the CESRM~\cite{ref:cesrm}.
%
% We piggy-back on the standard \textsf{fullpage} package, but use one
% of the internal variables |\FP@margin|, so we need to declare this
% length if it does not exist.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{fullpage}
\ifx\FP@margin\undefined
  \newlength{\FP@margin}
\fi
\setlength{\FP@margin}{1.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2\FP@margin}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\FP@margin}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
```

As suggested by Werner, the File list from .log is as follows:

```
*File List*
uw-wkrpt.cls    2003/05/20 v2.6 U. of Waterloo work reports
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
fullpage.sty    1999/02/23 1.1 (PWD)
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
mathptmx.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS) 
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
chngcntr.sty    2009/09/02 v1.0a change counter resetting
ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
ot1ztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OT1/ztmcm.
omlztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OML/ztmcm.
omsztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMS/ztmcm.
omxztmcm.fd    2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMX/ztmcm.
figures/wireless-router-network.jpg
figures/hwlayout.pdf
figures/linksysmain.jpg
omsptm.fd    
figures/ddwrtmain.jpg
figures/wantest.pdf
uw-wkrpt-ece.bbl
***********
```

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with `{}` on it).

Comment: This `.dtx` file you mention, is that the document class? As in, `uw-wkrpt.dtx`? There should be a `uw-wkrpt.cls` file which represents the document class. What was the actual code that you used with `geometry`: `\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in]{geometry}`? If this did/does not work, add `\listfiles` *above* `\documentclass` and compile. Then, extract all the information contained within your `.log` file after `**File List**` (near the end of the `.log` file) and include it in your post. This will give us an indication of package dates and perhaps some conflicts.

Comment: A minimal document with the [`uw-wkrpt` document class](http://sfllaw.ca/programs/uw-wkrpt/) including *only* [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with options `\usepackage[paperwidth=4in,paperheight=4in,margin=.5in]{geometry}` yields a `4in`x`4in` page with the appropriate margins. As such, you must be doing something different. Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that duplicates your problem. Do so by stripping everything while still having the problem, and post exactly that.

Answer (score 6):

This is completely normal, since [Nimbus Roman No9 L](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Roman_No9_L) could be considered the "free version" of the regular Times New Roman. The [`mathptmx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) selects this font as the default font for the document, and provides math and symbol support from other fonts. For actually using the Times True Type Font (TTF), [much more work is required](http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm), with perhaps a similar outcome (if not worse, in terms of math usage). The [`txfonts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) also provides "Times-like" math support.

For modifying the page margin, the best option would be to use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). You can modify the margins at package load by specifying

```
\usepackage[<options>]{geometry}
```

or by using `\geometry{<options>}` after loading the package. Margins are modified using a comma separated key-value approach such as `top=1in` (leaves a `1in` top margin), `bottom=2cm` (leaves a `2cm` bottom margin), `left=50pt` (leaves a `50pt` left margin) and `right=20bp` (leaves a `20bp` right margin). Alternatively, for equal margins, use `margin=15mm` (say), which sets all four to be the same. See the [`geometry` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) for more key-value options, and how to set them.